# Check if variable is used in Bamboo build plan

Tags: bamboo

Is there way to check if a certain plan variable is used in any steps in Bamboo build plan? Plan has multiple stages and each stage has few dozen steps, each step is about 1k script, so checking all manually would be time consuming.

Alternatively, is there way to export all build plan steps and stages into one or multiple text files?